# How to override method and event in WinForm UserControl in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a custom control in C# WinForms called `BaseControl` and there I have a property called `Selected`.

I want to have an event `SelectedChanged` and virtual method `OnSelecteChanged` in the base control and they should behave in the same manner as we have in `Control` class for many properties i.e. `Click` event and `OnClick` method.

Means anyone who derives from my `BaseControl` can either bind to the event or can override the `OnSelectedChanged` method.

So, when the value of `Selected` property is changed event should be fired and if the method is overridden control should go to that method.

I know how to fire the event but don't know how to do it for method.

Please guide me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is an example of how events should be implemented:

```
public class BaseControl : Control
{
    private object _selected;

    public object Selected
    {
        get { return _selected; }
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_selected, value))
            {
                _selected = value;
                OnSelectedChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler SelectedChanged;

    protected virtual void OnSelectedChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SelectedChanged != null)
            SelectedChanged(this, e);
    }
}
```

With this example, you can override `OnSelectedChanged` in an overriden class, like this:

```
public class MyControl : BaseControl
{
    protected override void OnSelectedChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSelectedChanged(e);

        // My own logic.
    }
}
```

Comment: Your OnSelectedChanged implementation contains a potential threading issue (what happens if between the null check and the firing of the event the last listener unsubscribes? --> You get a NullReferenceException)

Comment: @SchlaWiener - For UI programming this is not an issue because it's accepted that UI controls are **not** multi threading safe and should only be accessed from a single thread. But yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
private bool _selected;

public bool Selected
{
    get { return _selected; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _selected)
        {
            _selected = value;
            OnSelectedChanged();
        }
    }
}

public event EventHandler SelectedChanged;

protected virtual void OnSelectedChanged()
{
    var handler = SelectedChanged;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you don't fire the event from your `Selected` property setter - you call the method, and make the method call the event. Anyone overriding the method should call `base.OnSelectedChanged` to make sure the event still fires. So your method should look something like this:

```
protected virtual void OnSelectedChanged(EventArgs e) {
    EventHandler handler = Selected; // Or your own delegate variable
    if (handler != null) {
        handler(this, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you copy the event handler?