# How to get the old value of a TrackBar without a custom control or separate field?

Tags: winforms

I am trying to get the old `Value` of a `TrackBar` when the `Scroll` event gets raised. I could do this by creating a separate field and storing that value whenever it changes, or overriding the event in a custom control however,  I am already using the built-in `TrackBar` and I'd prefer to not have to redesign my forms.

The Microsoft documentation does not seem to have any information on this and the `EventArgs` parameter on the `OnScroll` and `OnValueChanged` methods seem pretty generic.

Is there a way to achieve this and how?

*Sources:*

[Microsoft Documentation: TrackBar.OnScroll Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar.onscroll(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Microsoft Documentation: TrackBar.Scroll Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar.scroll(v=vs.110).aspx)

[How to override method and event in WinForm UserControl in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194782/how-to-override-method-and-event-in-winform-usercontrol-in-c)

[Microsoft Documentation: TrackBar.ValueChanged Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar.valuechanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Microsoft Documentation: TrackBar.Value Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar.value(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Microsoft Documentation: TrackBar.OnValueChanged Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar.onvaluechanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: What do you mean by *without a custom control*? Do you mean you don't want to derive from `Tackbar` and override its methods to gain what you need?

Comment: @RezaAghaei Yes that's correct. That would mean I would have to replace all the existing `TrackBar`s in my forms which I am trying to avoid if possible.

Comment: Replacing existing controls is the easiest part. Find/Replace. So focus on the solution without putting such limitation on the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there isn't a built-in way to achieve what you're looking for.

To address your concern about having to replace all the `TrackBar` controls on a form with the derived custom control, here's how I usually do it:

1. Create your control class which inherits the `TrackBar` control.
2. Open your `FormName.Designer.cs` or `FormName.Designer.vb` file.
3. Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the "Find and replace" window.
4. Enter `System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar` in the "Find" field, and `YourNameSpace.CustomTrackBar` in the "Replace with" field.
5. Click "Replace all" *(You can do it one by one if you're afraid to mess something up)*.
6. Rebuild your project.

Hope that helps.